# JAVA - LWJGL - Texture rotation

Tags: java, rotation, lwjgl

Can somebody tell me real quick how to rotate a texture by var degrees in lwjgl when you have the coordinates
and the origin?
Well, it looks like that right now:
x/y are the center of the texture.

```
public void render(float x, float y) {
    glPushMatrix();
    texture.bind();

    glTranslatef(x - xOrigin, y - yOrigin, 0);

    //This is false. ignore it
    //glRotatef(45f, 0f, 0f, 1f);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);

        glTexCoord2f(0, width);
        glVertex2f(0, height);

        glTexCoord2f(texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
        glVertex2f(width, height);

        glTexCoord2f(texture.getWidth(), 0);
        glVertex2f(width, 0);
    }
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate textures you just need to change the UV coordinates, thereby rearranging the `glTexCoord2f(U, V)` though just be rearranging the them will only rotate them roughly 90deg/1.57rad per rearrange, though if you want smaller rotations of the texture, you can just calculate the U, V coordinates yourself using trigonometry cos and sin functions.